# How to generate a self-signed certificate that uses SNI?

Tags: apache, openssl, sni

OK -- I give.   I have a project I've been asked to do, and I want tot test it (people tell me testing is good).  I am trying to test some router logic that watches SNI-enhanced certificates.  I can generate a self-signed cert with OpenSSL, and Apache can be built to use SNI, but how do I tell OpenSSL to generate a self-signed cert with the SNI string?  In the end, I want something like this:

- Domain=disruptix.com
- Subdomains and their certs red.disruptix.com, green.disruptix.com, blue.disruptix.com
- I'll generate three certs for red, green and blue, each with SNI strings of red, green and blue.
- Router logic will sniff for the SNIs, looking for red, green or blue.disruptix.com and apply appropriate traffic steering policies.

I know SNI really isn't the thing to use, but I'm told that's what is wanted.  How do I create those self-signed certs?

Answer (score 0):

To create a self-signed cert, create a directory just for this, and run the following command:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.key -x509 -days 365 -out certificate.crt
```

This above command will generate a 2048 bit RSA certificate that is valid for 365 days. I am not sure if there is anything particular about sni, except that you use a shared IP address. And, to set it up, use name based virtualhosts, check out https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI for more information.

It is basically configured like this:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
ServerAdmin email@example1.com
ServerName example1.com #This says that if the ip is accessed through example1.com, display the document root for example1.com, and take all the config from this virtualhost
DocumentRoot /path/to/document/root/for/example1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
ServerAdmin email@example2.com
ServerName example2.com #This says that if the ip is accessed through example1.com, display the document root for example2.com, and take all the config from this virtualhost
DocumentRoot /path/to/document/root/for/example2.com
</VirtualHost>
```